# aws s3 website hosting, setting permissions for private keys file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, web

I have a static website hosted on an aws s3 bucket.  I am using a few different api's like google, trello etc.  I am not sure how to keep some of these keys private as I set up my bucket to use `PublicReadForGetBucketObjects` which makes the entire website public.  I have looked into `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` and permissions to restrict access but still cannot figure out how to make one of my files private.  It seems to me that this is probably something easy but I cannot find a way.

Here is what my bucket policy looks like

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[my bucket]/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The policy you have listed can apply permissions **based on path**. For example, setting the Resource to `arn:aws:s3:::[my bucket]/public/*` would only make the public sub-directory public (or more accurately, any path that starts with `/public/`).

Similarly, a policy can also define a path to specifically **Deny**, which will override the Allow (so you could make everything public but then specifically deny certain files and paths)

However, you mention that you would like to keep some files private, yet this is a static website, with no compute component. It would not be possible for only 'some' of your website to access the desired objects, since all the logic is taking place in your users' browsers rather than on your web server. Therefore, a file would either be public or private, but the private files could not be accessed as part of the static website. This might not be what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  It is indeed not what I am trying to acheive.